# Element api JSON output formatting

Tags: plugin-elementapi, json

I want to output all globals with one endpoint. This is trivial for the most part but I need to have some objects in a specific shape.

I'm using a matrix block to handle the content. The main issue I have is I need the json for the `footerLinks` array to be:

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "footerLinks": [
                {
                    "title": "Legal information",
                    "items":[
                        {
                            "link": "Cookies and privacy",
                            "url": "/cookies-privacy"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "About Company",
                    "items":[
                        {
                            "link": "What we do",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "link": "Contact us",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "link": "Accessibility",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "title": "Statistics",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "link": "Authority",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        },

                        {
                            "link": "Releases",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        },
                        {
                            "link": "News",
                            "url": "https://someurl.com"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is the code I have so far:

```
        'api/globals.json' => function() {
            $langHandle = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('lang', 'en');
            return [
                'elementType' => GlobalSet::class,
                'criteria' => ['site' => $langHandle],
                'transformer' => function(GlobalSet $globalSet) {
                    $footerBlocks = [];
                    foreach ($globalSet->globals as $block) {
                        switch ($block->type->handle) {
                            case 'listItem':
                                $footerBlocks[] = [ 
                                    array(
                                        'link' => $block->listText,
                                        'url' => $block->listUrl,
                                    )
                                ];
                            break;
                            case 'listHeader':
                                $footerBlocks[] = [
                                    'title' => $block->listTitle,
                                ];
                            break;
                        }   
                    }
                    return [
                        'footerLinks' => $footerBlocks,
                    ];
                }
            ];
        }
```

And this is the current output:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "footerLinks": [
        {
          "title": "Legal information"
        },
        [
          {
            "link": "Cookies and privacy",
            "url": "/cookies-privacy"
          }
        ],
        {
          "title": "About"
        },
        [
          {
            "link": "What we do",
            "url": "https://someurl.com"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "link": "Contact us",
            "url": "/contact-us"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "link": "Accessibility",
            "url": "https://someurl.com"
          }
        ],
        {
          "title": "Statistics"
        },
        [
          {
            "link": "Authority",
            "url": "https://someurl.com"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "link": "Release calendar",
            "url": "https://someurl.com"
          }
        ],
        [
          {
            "link": "News",
            "url": "https://someurl.com"
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
  ],
```

And this is a screenshot of the matrix block:

[image]

Essentially I need to create a new object for each `listHeader` and `listItem` set and also wrap each set of `listItem` objects in an array called `items`. Currently it doesn't group anything together and outputs each individual `listItem` in an array.

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```php
'api/globals.json' => function() {
    $langHandle = Craft::$app->request->getQueryParam('lang', 'en');
    return [
        'elementType' => GlobalSet::class,
        'criteria' => ['site' => $langHandle],
        'transformer' => function(GlobalSet $globalSet) {
            // start with -1 so the first one will be 0 if you start with a listHeader
            // this is your current index
            $index = -1;
            // the data you like to return
            $data = [];
            foreach ($globalSet->globals as $block) {
                switch ($block->type->handle) {
                    case 'listHeader':
                        // new header, increase the index, store the title and an empty items array
                        $index++;
                        $data[$index]['title'] = $block->listTitle;
                        $data[$index]['items'] = [];
                        break;
                    case 'listItem':
                        // include the listItem to the current index as item
                        $data[$index]['items'][] = [
                            'link' => $block->listText,
                            'url' => $block->listUrl,
                        ];
                        break;
                }
            }
            return [
                'footerLinks' => $data,
            ];
        }
    ];
}
```

Comment: Yes that does work. Thank you very much. Very simple solution!